# How to detect if the base classs constructor is called from a derived class constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, c++20

There is a hierarchy of classes, say, `Base -> A -> B`.

Whenever `A::A()` is called, the actual to-be-constructed object may be either of class `A`, and then it is the last ctor called; or of class `B`, and then `B::B()` will be called later. Is it possible to distinguish between these cases and detect whether the constructor currently being called belongs to the type that is actually being constructed?

The compelling solution is to use `typeid`:

```
A::A() {
    if (typeid(this) == typeid(A*)) {
        // A is the actual type of the object being constructed
    }
}
```

However, `typeid` (as well as vtables) works differently in constructors and destructors and do not expose the final class, instead returning the information about the current (static) class itself. This is due to that the constructors of classes deeper in the hierarchy hadn't been called yet and thus it would be illegal to access them from an already constructed parent. See the last paragraph in the Explanation section at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

I do not need to know the exact type of the object being constructed but only need to detect whether the current constructor is the final one. Is it possible to do it?

I can modify the body of a `Base` class and the constructors of all other classes. Bodies of `A` and `B` are out of my control.

C++20 will be fine.

**Edit**: I'll try to elaborate which pieces of code I can modify and which cannot.

First of all, I have the full access to `Base`. It is always the very base class of the hierarchy.

Then the users of the library may define descendant classes like this:

```
class A : public Base
{
    REGISTER(A);

    // some user code
};

class B : public A
{
    REGISTER(B);

    // some other user code
};
```

The `REGISTER` macro is provided by the library. In particular, it defines the constructor of a specific type (that's how I can control it). If the user defines other constructors, the behavior is undefined, so we can assume that our constructor is the only one. Note that we do not know the bases' names so we cannot explicitly call `A`'s ctor from `B`; furthermore, there may be multiple bases, even virtual ones.

The trick that I'm looking for will be placed into the `REGISTER` macro.

Comment: Provide info in constructor: `template <typename T> Base(std::type_identity<T>);`?

Comment: @Jarod42 If I understand correctly, it would require to modify all places where the classes are constructed, wouldn't it?

Comment: It would be sufficient to set this only in thr inheriting class constructors. You can even make that overload protected so that only these can use that constructor.

Comment: Not necessary, you might use forwarding constructors, (so just change `Base`, `A`, `B`).

Comment: @Jarod42 The hierarchy is generic, it is a library code and the hierarchy is built by users. I cannot call `A`'s ctor in `B` explicitly. I'll add the edit to the question.

Comment: What type of decisions will be made depending on if it's an `A` or a `B` that's being instantiated?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Simplifed explanation: besides calling `REGISTER`, users provide some more information to the library. It is collected recursively through the hierarchy via static meta-objects. Upon the construction I need to perform some heavy initialization of the object based on that information. The initialization is very heavy so I want to avoid calling it multiple times all the way to the top, executing only once when the final class is constructed.

Comment: If `A` constructor is called multiple times, it's because `A` is inherited multiple times (non-`virtual`ly), or am I misunderstanding something? If you actually want two `A` instances in a derived class, then shouldn't both be initialized?

Comment: Can't you have factory method?

Comment: @Jarod42 We actually have factory method now and are thinking how to get rid of it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, I mean that the initialization will happen both in `A` ctor and `B` ctor, but only the result from `B` ctor is needed. So I want to skip the initialization in the non-final constructors because it is a useless work.

Comment: If `B` inherits from `A` that inherits from `Base`, then instantiating a `B` will only initialize `A` once. In `B`s constructor, the `A` part is already fully initialized. If you need it to be initialized differently, then `B` needs to provide some information about how to `A`s constructor.

Comment: I thing that a virtual base could do the trick as only the most derived class would call it. Otherwise, have 2 constructors at each level (except Base if it is abstract) : one public contructor for cleint code use and a protected one with some extra parameters for derived classes. Then all public constructors would call a protected inherited constructor and then call the initialisation function. A third alternative might be to have "virtual constructor" by calling a virtual `Init` function right after construction. If classes are created by some factory method, it might be a good alternative.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov I'd like to know more details about _"only the result from `B` ctor is needed"_.  Can you expand your example to show what this means? Are the initialized resources know to `A`?  Would passing the initialized resources down _from_ `B` be an option? [example](https://godbolt.org/z/qvYsT63cP)

Comment: @Phil1970 I'm a friend of Ivan so we both struggle to find viable solution here. 1. We have virtual base, but our heavy initialization cannot take place there as typeid(this) returns TBase's typeid, not most derived class. 2. Second constructor doesn't work as our REGISTER macro knows only TThis class, not parent classes, so we can't call specific base class constructor explicitly. 3. We actually have factory method now and we made default constructor private to prevent constructing uninitialized instances. But private constructors impose heavy limitations on classes.

Comment: Remove the `REGISTER` macro. it's a black-box for us and rather non-idiomatic in C++. We can't provide properly useful answers with that `REGISTER` macro, that we don't know anything about, in the way. `typeid` inspections also tells me that you are solving this the wrong way. Drop that idea and clearly show what you want to do without any black-boxes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I made a simplified [sketch](https://godbolt.org/z/nbEWjqdEb) in Godbolt. Hope it helps to understand requirements.

Comment: @renadeen Frankly, that's a horrible macro i.m.o. It serves no other purpose than to obscure and confuse - and most probably to inhibit solutions striving to do the opposite.

Comment: [1/2] Regarding `typeid`... It's not that we're solving this the wrong way, it that weird problems require weird solutions. Parts of our code require calling `dynamic_cast<IntermediateType*>(base)`, where `base` always has physical type `TLibraryBase`. The dynamic cast is in the hot path, so we use dynamic cast caching: given the target type, dynamic cast from `TLibraryBase` can be performed just with adding some known offset to the pointer. However, this offset depends not only on target type but on the final type as well, where the final type can be retrieved with `typeid`.

Comment: [2/2] So we cache the offset of the dynamic cast from `TLibraryBase`, where hashing key is the pair (static target type, dynamic final type). The quirk is that we want to use that dynamic cast cache in `HeavyInit` in constructors but it is impossible since `typeid` returns different final type in constructors than it really is. This is why we want to detect whether the constructor is final.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov _"it that weird problems require weird solutions"_ & _"Parts of our code require..."_ both seem like things you can do something about.  I've never used `typeid` other than to log something on occation. It's not an operator I recommend using in production code.  Too bad this isn't a "design this application" type of site because it seems like you should take a step back and rethink this.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I agree at your point of view in general; would anyone asked me if they should use `typeid`, I would give the same answer as you did. The full explanation and reasoning here do not fit in the margin. I hope someday we'll make an opensource documented version of the library and explain in detail all design considerations that may look strange and unnecessary at first place. I'll invite you to check it out once it happens.

Comment: I appreciate you helping me solve the XY-problem. I have enough production experience with C++ to understand that what we're doing here seems to be really against the guidelines. But I'm still interested to the answer to my original question; at least from the language lawyer point of view.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov Cool! I'm on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) too, so just tag me there.

Comment: _"the answer to my original question"_ - That is detecting if it's the final initialization in a default constructor? Hmm, must say I've never thought about it because I've never needed to think about it :-) I _will_ think about it though, but I don't think it's possible. If I get an "aha" experience, I'll return.

Comment: Simple answer : you cannot know the derived type from a  base constructor. An alternative thing you might look is the CRTP (Curiously recurring template pattern). **Honestly, if you need to do that much dynamic_cast in your code to a point it is problematic, then you should learn to properly use virtual functions.**

Comment: *"the actual to-be-constructed object may be either of class A, and then it is the last ctor called; or of class B, and then B::B() will be called later."* - this assumption is wrong, if `B` is the type of actually constructed object then `B::B()` will be invoked first and then it will invoke `A`'s and other base class constructors. *"I can modify the body of a Base class and the constructors of all other classes."* - ¿then why not explicitly supply an extra argument to the constructor of the base class, indicating whether it is invoked from the constructor of the derived class?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for taking part in discussion! We've come up with solution based on comment of @Phil1970

> thing that a virtual base could do the trick as only the most derived class would call it.

The brief advice guided us to an excellent solution. We can invoke the constructor of special virtually inherited base class by passing current typeid in every constructor within our hierarchy. Special base class will store provided typeid. Upon constructing an instance, the call of base constructor will be executed only in the most derived class. And finally in every constructor we just check whether current class typeid is the same as passed to virtual base. See details in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8bToez3bM).

For @Phil1970: if you make separate answer with these details we'll make it accepted.